# WebSocket without SSL doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: c#, javascript, google-chrome, websocket

In 2013 I tried Websockets out with Alchemy (http://alchemywebsockets.net/). Now I'm trying to make a new project, but the WebSocket doesn't receive or send nothing.

I did do some research and found a website where you can test WebSockets (http://www.websocket.org/echo.html), the weird part is that without SSL/TLS WebSockets doesn't even work.

Now, I found a project called web-socket-js which uses Flash as WebSocket, it works great on FireFox, but it still fails in Chrome.

I hope someone can help me out,

I'm using the following codes:

*Server Side:*

```
public WSServer()
{
    WSServer.Instance = this;

    this.webSocketServer = new WebSocketServer(81, IPAddress.Any)
    {
        OnConnected = OnConnected,
        OnReceive = OnReceive,
        OnDisconnect = OnDisconnect,
        TimeOut = new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0)
    };
    this.webSocketServer.Start();

    Console.WriteLine("Started Server");
}

private void OnConnected(UserContext context)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Connected!");
}

private void OnDisconnect(UserContext context)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Disconnected");
}

private void OnReceive(UserContext context)
{
    string dataString = context.DataFrame.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("Got message " + dataString);
}
```

*Client Side:*

```
try{
    socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:81/");

    socket.onopen = function(){
        console.log("Connection open!");
    };

    socket.onmessage = function(msg){
        console.log("Message: " + msg);
    };

    socket.onclose = function(){
        console.log("Connection closed.");
    };      
} catch(exception){
     console.log('Error: ' + exception);
}
```

Comment: Related: [WebSocket connection fails on Chrome without SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50704614/websocket-connection-fails-on-chrome-without-ssl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there was a bug with Google Chrome. In the last version of Google Chrome websockets without SSL works fine now.