# WebSocket connection fails on Chrome without SSL

Tags: ssl, websocket, tomcat7

I'm setting up a WebSocket between a standard web page and a Tomcat v7.0.62 server.  The connection works fine with Tomcat SSL turned on/off on Firefox, Edge and IE11.  However, in Chrome (v66.03), the websocket only connects when I've turned on SSL on the server and connect via https.  In Chrome, when I turn SSL off on the server and try to connect via http, it throws an error.

Here's the error Chrome throws when trying to connect via http with SSL turned off on Tomcat...

```
Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_PROXY_AUTH_REQUESTED_WITH_NO_CONNECTION
```

Here's my WebSocket connection code on the client...

```
var wss = "wss://";
if (document.location.protocol === "http:") {
   wss = "ws://";
}
var wsURL = wss + document.location.host + "/status?sessionId=<%=session.getId()%>";
```

Is this something Chrome specific that needs special code on non-https websocket connections?

Comment: would you please put your server configuration and code , also put full client code ?

Comment: **Sidenote**: consider `ver wss = "ws" + document.location.protocol.slice(4);`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a Chrome specific behavior. Chrome doesn't allow unsecure websocket (ws) connections to localhost (only wss, so you should setup a TLS certificate for your local web/websocket server). But the same should work without any issues in Firefox and other browsers.

Please refer the Chrome bug report on Chromium regarding this issue. This particular problem is intentional, and they have made this change to make 
Chrome more secure by preventing attacks against internal network devices and processes listening on localhost.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=378566

Answer (score 1):

```
Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_PROXY_AUTH_REQUESTED_WITH_NO_CONNECTION
```

It seems you might have a proxy with authentication in the middle, between the clients and the service. Depending on the proxy and clients configuration, it might let through SSL connections, but plain http will get filtered.

Answer (score 0):

I can not confirm your issue. You can try the Echo Test here: http://www.websocket.org/echo.html

The website supports http and https, you can specify `ws://echo.websocket.org` and `wss://echo.websocket.org`. I have tried all combinations and they all worked for me.

My guess is that it is a configuration issue with your server or a problem with your browser extensions.

Comment: Yeah, that's just it.  I don't get any issues when I go to echo.websocket.org.  My clients, using the same version of Chrome, will get that Error in connection establishment when they go to echo.websocket.org

Comment: Well, then tell your clients to fix their browser I guess. There is not much you can do if they use extensions that enforce certain security policies, block certain scripts or connections, or inject code into the site etc.

Comment: I did your test today, 2 years later, the result is: "Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS."

Comment: I used this code in my webbrowser where I instantiate a WebSocket using 2 parameters. The second is the protocol:
`exampleSocket = new WebSocket("ws://"+ip+":"+port, "protocolOne");`

Just remove the second parameter and it worked:
`exampleSocket = new WebSocket("ws://"+ip+":"+port);`

Comment: It seems like the service is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

To allow the WS on Chrome if you are using Java service need to  `setAllowedOrigins` to `setWebSocketHandlerRegistry` for desired origin or `*` in case to keep it open:

```
public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addHandler(new SocketTextHandler(), "/<end-point>").setAllowedOrigins("<my-origin>");
}
```

No wss needed.