# chrome extenstion background - socket.io connect to https instead of http

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-extension, socket.io

I'm using **Socket.io** for Google Chrome extension in background to connect to a http socket server. But whatever I put into the code, the socket.io always try to connect to `https` instead of `http`. How can I force socket client to always connect over http?

I'm calling the function from a context page on a https page, is that the problem?

```
socket = io.connect( 'http://192.168.1.2:5000/?id=10&token=abjnhikn==' , {secure: false} );
socket.connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome does not seem to allow connections that are not secure, I think you have the same question as this one: [WebSocket connection fails on Chrome without SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50704614/websocket-connection-fails-on-chrome-without-ssl)