# Error Connecting to Substrate Front-End Template when connecting remotely

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, substrate

I m trying out substrate installation and building chains from this tutorial here - https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/create-your-first-substrate-chain/interact

I did `cargo build --release` on node template and started the server by `./target/release/node-template --dev --tmp`. then started the frontend app by doing `yarn start`. Now, I am trying to access the page remotely on my browser by hitting - `<node-ip-address>:8000/substrate-front-end-template` I am getting the following:

`Error Connecting to Substrate [object Event]`

Upon inspecting the browser, I get the following:

```
Provider.js:380 WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:9944/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
connect @ Provider.js:380 connectWithRetry @ Provider.js:402 (anonymous) @ Provider.js:175
index.js:1 2020-10-11 20:34:00 API-WS: disconnected from ws://127.0.0.1:9944: 1006:: Abnormal Closure
```

Looks like my browser is not able to establish a secure connection to the app. How do I fix this? Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What browser are you using? Can you try maybe in a different browser? I think many people use Firefox or Chrome, if that's not already what you're using.

Comment: @ Dan Forbes I am using chrome.

Comment: Can you try with Firefox?

Comment: You may be hitting this error https://stackoverflow.com/a/50861413/858003

Answer (score 2):

If you start the network with an external rpc enabled, it works!
Updated command:

```
./target/release/node-template --dev --tmp --ws-external --rpc-external
```